# Angular routing boostrap tabs with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, router, bootstrap-tabs

Hi there I am struggling to get my bootstrap tabs/ angular router to work through webpack. Without using webpack it works fine.

Error I am getting is `Error: Argument 'TabsDesktopCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

Need to know how to get it working properly?

1. Output the routes folder into the build directory?
2. Load angular scripts?

New to webpack, any help is much appreciated!

Structure

```
build
src
/images
/js
--/angular_routing.js
--/...
/scss
/routes
--/settings.html
...
/index.js
/template.html
webpack.common.js
webpack.dev.js
webpack.prod.js
```

Here is my files

**/src/js/angular_routing.js**

```
var app = angular.module('profile-page', []);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider.
    when('/titanfx-account', { templateUrl: './routes/account.html', controller: MainCtrl }).
    when('/trader-client-cabinet', { templateUrl: './routes/trader.html', controller: MainCtrl }).
    when('/intro-broker-ib', { templateUrl: './routes/broker', controller: MainCtrl }).
    when('/history-notes', { templateUrl: './routes/history-notes.html', controller: MainCtrl }).
    when('/settings', { templateUrl: './routes/settings.html', controller: MainCtrl }).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/account.html' });
}]);
function TabsDesktopCtrl($scope, $location) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { link: '#/account', label: 'Account' },
    { link: '#/trader', label: 'Trader' },
    { link: '#/broker', label: 'Broker' },
    { link: '#/history-notes', label: 'History / Notes' },
    { link: '#/settings', label: 'Settings' }
  ];
  $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[0];
  $scope.setSelectedTab = function (tab) {
    $scope.selectedTab = tab;
  }
  $scope.tabClass = function (tab) {
    if ($scope.selectedTab == tab) {
      return "active";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

**/src/template.html** (using HtmlWebpackPlugin)

```
<html ng-app="profile-page">
...
<script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
<!--Tab View Desktop -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-desktop" ng-controller="TabsDesktopCtrl">
<li ng-class="tabClass(tab)" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" tab="tab"><a href="{{tab.link}}" data-target="#"
                ng-click="setSelectedTab(tab)">{{tab.label}}</a></li>
</ul>

<!--Main View -->
<div ng-view></div>
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
entry: {
  main: "./src/index.js",
  angular_routing: "./src/js/angular_routing.js",
  angular_tabs: "./src/js/angular_tabs.js",
  inline: "./src/js/inline.js",
  user_profile_js: "./src/js/user_profile_js.js"
},
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        use: {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "images"
            }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        use: {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "images"
            }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
            "html-loader"
        ]
      }

    ]
}
};
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin"); 
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
mode: "production",
output: {
    filename: "[name].[contentHash].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build")
},
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
        new TerserPlugin()
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
        {
            filename: "[name].[contentHash].css"
        }
    ), 
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        {
            template: "./src/template.html"
        }
    )
],
module:{
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader",
                "sass-loader"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is because the function `TabsDesktopCtrl` is out of scope. At a guess I'm going to say that without webpack Angular will just resolve the global function.

A very hack way that I don't recommend in any way, Would be to declare the function globally like so:

`window.TabsDesktopCtrl = function ($scope, $location)
 {
   //etc...
 }`

The above will not address the bigger issue which is with webpack and how this is implemented. There are far better guides out there on this though.

https://webpack.js.org/concepts
https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/